# Downloading a Csv file From angularjs Jax-Rs and java

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

Hello everyone i am using angularjs java and rest to implement one report. Based on UI field selected there is a call to Java Layer and from java there is some database call and the returned input stream i am downloading in a csv file.
There is one problem happening if i do the same with hitting the the same url by browser which i m passing through angularjs than i m able to download the file but if by using UI i m making the request than there is no download option and data is returned as a stream in http response to angular.

java code:

```
enter code here
    @Path("/files")
    public class DownloadCsvFile {

   @GET
   @Path("/csv")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
   public Response getFile() {
   StreamingOutput outp = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, 
        WebApplicationException { 
        String url ="http://someurl?
        indent=on&q=RCE_POST:2016&sort=id%20asc
        &rows=100000&start=0&wt=csv";
        final InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
                    ((HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection())
                    .getInputStream(),
                     Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

         IOUtils.copy(is, out);
        }   
    };

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(outp);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
    filename=\"testFile_file.csv\"");
    return response.build();

       }  }
```

AngularJs controller code :

```
enter code here
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngProgress']);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,ngProgressFactory) {
        // on submit the fun is called
        $scope.LMALLPeriodReport =function()
        {
          return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/IsaveIdeas/rest/files/csv?
          parameters="+parameter)
          //parameter contain the selected field in UI
          .then(function (response) {
           var result = response.data;
           alert("printing data");
         });
        };
```

The same request from the browser http://localhost:8080/IsaveIdeas/rest/files/csv? parameters={parameter} enable me to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blob in your angularjs code like this:

```
....
.then(function (response) {

var fileName = "yourFileName.csv";
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
response.data = "\ufeff" + response.data;
var file = new Blob([response.data], {encoding:"UTF-8",type:'application/csv;charset=UTF-8'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.href = fileURL;
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
}
```